# MySQL User-Defined Functions Multiple Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, mysql

I am a student and now taking care of a lab server configured by a former student.

This morning I received an email from the university technology department issuing that

```
> MySQL User-Defined Functions Multiple Vulnerabilities 
> There is currently no known fix or patch to address these issues. Instead, make
> sure access to create user-defined functions is restricted.
```

I am not familiar with database. The port 3306 has been disabled but I am still wondering how to solve the problem. I did some google search but no obvious result.
The server does have some security update related to Mysql.

Is doing a security update enough to address this problem, or is there any way I can restrict user access to MySQL user-defined function?

Comment: You want to be sure you setup the function with explicit permission to only `GRANT` it access to the specific user and/or host which should be executing it. Look up "*How to grant permission to user-defined function MySQL*" or something along those lines with Google. Be sure to check how the security to it is set, remove that security if it's too much, and then grant only those and from the hosts which you need to have access to it. You'll need to do a little reading/home and then test with some dummy test accounts. It's not difficult so get to work on it.

Comment: A security update is not a suitable fix according to the email you got - it specifically states that there is no known fix or patch.  Port 3306 not being open does not help, as presumably database is manipulated through queries done via another interface on the local machine (eg web request talking to mysql over a file socket)